Cards moves sideway but don't function like a carousel
I'm trying to create a carousel identical to the SlideSwiper from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_carousel.
The cards move sideways, but they don't function at all like a carousel.
Please help me!
final List\<String\> items = \[
'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/300/200',
'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200',
'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/300/200',
'https://picsum.photos/id/1020/300/200',
'https://picsum.photos/id/1021/300/200',
\];
int currentIndex = 0;
final double boxWidth = 300;
final double boxHeight = 150;
final double centerBoxHeight = 200;
late AnimationController \_controller;
late Animation\<double\> \_animation;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
\_controller = AnimationController(
duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
vsync: this,
);
}

@override
void dispose() {
\_controller.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

void \_moveNext() {
setState(() {
currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % items.length;
});
}

void \_movePrevious() {
setState(() {
currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + items.length) % items.length;
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final basePosition = screenWidth / 2;

    // 표시할 인덱스들 (순환)
    List<int> visibleIndices = [
      (currentIndex - 1 + items.length) % items.length,
      currentIndex,
      (currentIndex + 1) % items.length
    ];
    
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 400,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            // 현재 인덱스가 아닌 카드들 먼저 렌더링
            ...visibleIndices
                .where((index) => index != currentIndex)
                .map((index) => _buildBox(index, basePosition)),
    
            // 가운데 카드를 마지막에 렌더링
            _buildBox(currentIndex, basePosition),
    
            // 좌측 네비게이션 버튼
            Positioned(
              left: 16,
              top: 150,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                onPressed: _movePrevious,
              ),
            ),
    
            // 우측 네비게이션 버튼
            Positioned(
              right: 16,
              top: 150,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                onPressed: _moveNext,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

}

Widget \_buildBox(int index, double basePosition) {
// 현재 인덱스와의 거리 계산
int indexDifference = \_calculateIndexDifference(index);

    bool middleBox = indexDifference == 0;
    
    // 높이
    double height = middleBox ? centerBoxHeight : boxHeight;
    
    // 색상
    Color color = middleBox ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5);
    
    // 위치 오프셋 계산
    double positionOffset = indexDifference * (boxWidth * 0.6);
    
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      left: basePosition - (boxWidth / 2) + positionOffset,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      child: Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001) // 원근감
          ..translate(0.0, 0.0, middleBox ? 1.0 : -1.0)
          ..scale(middleBox ? 1.0 : 0.9), // 중앙 카드 확대
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
            width: boxWidth,
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: Offset(0, 4),
                )
              ],
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              width: boxWidth,
              height: height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                child: Image.network(
                  items[index],
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                    if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                            ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                            : null,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.error,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );

}

// 현재 인덱스와 주어진 인덱스 사이의 상대적 위치 계산
int \_calculateIndexDifference(int index) {
// 순환적으로 인덱스 차이 계산
if (index == currentIndex) return 0;

    if (index == (currentIndex - 1 + items.length) % items.length) return -1;
    
    if (index == (currentIndex + 1) % items.length) return 1;
    
    return 0;

}
}

I want to create a carousel identical to the SlideSwiper from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_carousel.
Only three cards will be rendering
